# Files get uploaded as Type: Folder in Google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have been uploading .jpg files to GCS for a while and I have not changed my code which does this operation in the last 5 months.
About a month ago, I started to realize that some of my uploaded image files started to get listed as Type:Folder instead of Type:image/jpeg as they used to be.

[image]

The UI of the GCS has changed around a month ago and I have a feeling something in the background had also changed and it is either a Google bug (unlikely) or I have always been uploading the pictures the wrong way (Potentially with some wrong metadata or something that prevents GCS to recognize them as image/jpeg) and it just caught up to me with Google updating something.

Before I start digging deeper into my speculation of metadata, I wanted to ask here if anybody else has encountered the same problem. If yes, what was the fix?

Summary: no code change, around a month ago, GCS web UI started to list my "image/jpeg" as "Folder". Is anybody aware of a change from Google side that could make this happen?

Comment: How are you uploading the files? Also, what does `gsutil ls -L gs://bucket/object` say for one of the objects under `Content-Type`?

Comment: Thank you for the command, it made my suspicion that I was sending the files to the server wrong even stronger as it returned;

Content-Length: 371543
Content-Type: None

I added the answer to this question and accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue.
I had this code right before sending the file to the server;

```
String contentType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(stream);
```

this fails to recognize that it's image/jpeg because the picture's metadata is destroyed during all the image processing I do earlier.

Now, I hardcoded it and it works as follows

```
String contentType = "image/jpeg";
```

Solution: specify the contentType of the file before sending it to the server.